# python: getting element in a list

Tags: python

```
def do_work():
  medications_subset2(b,['HYDROCODONE','MORPHINE','OXYCODONE'])

def medications_subset2(b,drugs_needed):
  MORPHINE=['ASTRAMORPH','AVINZA','CONTIN','DURAMORPH','INFUMORPH',
            'KADIAN','MS CONTIN','MSER','MSIR','ORAMORPH',
            'ORAMORPH SR','ROXANOL','ROXANOL 100']
  print drugs_needed[1][0]
```

how do i print `ASTRAMORPH` (this is the first element in `MORPHINE`)

i NEED to make use of `drugs_needed`, since this is being passed in from `do_work`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you define MORPHINE this way?

```
drugs = {
  'MORPHINE': ['ASTRAMORPH',...],
  'HYDROCODONE': [...],
  ...
}
```

then you can refer to it by

```
print ( drugs[drugs_needed[1]][0] )
```

Comment: thank you very much. using this would how can iterate on all drugs in the morphine class?

Comment: @l: `for drug in drugs[drugs_needed[1]]: ...`

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH GOOOOOOOOD SIR

Comment: can you help with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3356209/python-complicated-loop-through-list